# Swift - Create radial line for button when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, calayer, programmatically-created

I was asked to create radial line effect programmatically when the button is pressed as seen below on button 7 but not sure exactly where to start to recreate this.

[image]

I am guessing this is done using a CALayer correct? I am not asking for the code but if someone could push me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: Use a background image?

Comment: the person says it's done programmatically but it would be easier just to do it with a background image

Comment: Well, the radials "look" almost like different colour pie slices, maybe using a `CAReplicatorLayer`

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer! I found a video on it and looks like it might work.

Comment: I would just have my app draw the radial line image, in code, as needed. Not difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've got a simple geometric pattern to draw, why not just draw it, in code? Here's my rendering of your radial image:

[image]

This is the complete code of the test app that generated it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let c1 = UIColor(red: 140/255.0, green: 240/255.0, blue: 209/255.0, alpha: 1)
        let c2 = UIColor(red: 59/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 123/255.0, alpha: 1)
        let iv = UIImageView(image:self.radialLinesImage(
            size:CGSize(width:200, height:200), div:20,
            c1:c1, c2:c2))
        iv.frame.origin = CGPoint(x:100, y:100)
        self.view.addSubview(iv)
    }
    func radialLinesImage(size:CGSize, div:CGFloat, c1:UIColor, c2:UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let r = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size)
        return r.image { ctx in
            c1.setFill()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(origin:.zero, size:size))
            c2.setFill()
            let p = UIBezierPath()
            let c = CGPoint(x:size.width/2, y:size.height/2)
            for i in 0..<Int(div) {
                let a = CGFloat.pi/(div/2) * CGFloat(i)
                p.addArc(withCenter: c,
                         radius: size.width+size.height,
                         startAngle: a, endAngle: a+CGFloat.pi/div,
                         clockwise: true)
                p.addLine(to: c)
                p.fill()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great on the UIButton Matt. Thanks again!